# Android screen off animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to create a screen off animation.

I have already implemented my BroadcastReceiver to receive the SCREEN_OFF action,
so can anyone please provide me with ideas or links of how can be this implemented?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think you can change the default behavior of the screen off animation.  I believe `SCREEN_OFF` is for actual actions to be performed during that time, not animations.  Hopefully, for your sake, I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_OFF):

> public static final String **ACTION_SCREEN_OFF**
>
> Since: *API Level 1*
>
> Broadcast Action: *Sent after the screen turns off.*
>
> ```
>     This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system.
>
> Constant Value: "android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"
> ```

This means that you wouldn't use this method to achieve what you're looking for because it doesn't do anything until **AFTER** the screen has already turned off.

Comment: Oh, you are absolutely right, I can't use SCREEN_OFF method. I know already some apps that produce animation before screen is off! What about this? How are this animations implemented? I know how to apply an animation on my own layout! But the thing about these apps is that they apply the animation on current view. For example if the launcher icon of [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.katecca.screenofflock&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5rYXRlY2NhLnNjcmVlbm9mZmxvY2siXQ..) app is on Home screen it will apply the animation on my home screen.

Comment: @JohnDe I just downloaded and installed the app that you referenced and it appears to me that they don't actually turn off the screen.  They merely cause some animation to occur and then show a black screen until the screen is turned off, thus giving the illusion that they have turned the screen off with their own unique animation.

Comment: Actually it is turning off the screen because if you connect your android on your pc and open the LogCat in Eclipse, you will see the SCREEN_OFF action. Anyway my question is how can I apply such an animation. e.g. on Home screen.

Comment: @JohnDe Sorry, I'm unable to help. Best of luck!